# ISBLANK and DATEDIF with two date columns where there are sometimes blanks in both

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I am trying to figure out the correct formula for my SharePoint calculated column. I have two date columns [Date in Queue] and [Date Completed]. I need to calculate number of days between the two dates and if there is no date completed then I need it to calculate number of days from date in queue to today.

The issue is I have blanks in both columns; my current formula produces some random 45,189 number when I have blanks for that first date.

How can I modify my formula to produce blank fields when there is blanks in both [Date in Queue] and [Date Completed], take the difference of the two dates and take the difference between [Date in Queue] to today when [Date Completed is blank].

Current Formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK([Date Completed])),DATEDIF([Date in Queue],TODAY(),"d"),IF(OR(NOT(ISBLANK([Date in Queue])),NOT(ISBLANK([Date Completed]))),DATEDIF([Date in Queue],[Date Completed],"d"),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using formula like below for your SharePoint calculated column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Completed]),IF(ISBLANK([Date in Queue]),"",DATEDIF([Date in Queue],TODAY(),"d")),IF(ISBLANK([Date in Queue]),"",DATEDIF([Date in Queue],[Date Completed],"d")))
```

---

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.